# In iOS 11, dismissing a modally presented navigation controller results in visual duplication

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchcontroller, ios11

I have a modally presented `UINavigationController`. Onto that navigation controller, two view controllers are pushed. The whole modal presentation should be dismissed from the second view controller upon pressing a Done button. To do this, dismiss is called on the `presentingViewController`:

```
@IBAction func doneWasPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    presentingViewController!.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

In iOS 11, when an ancestor within the navigation controller has presented a `UISearchController`, which is added to the `navigationItem`, dismissing the navigation controller causes a visual artefact whereby a duplicate of the view is visible *underneath* the animating view. Once the top view has moved out of view, the duplicate underneath suddenly disappears. See the gif below for a screen recording of the issue.

A small reproducible example is available in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/AndrewBennet/ModalDismissIssueExample). It was created on Xcode 9 (GM) using Swift 4.

Is there a known workaround?

---

[image]

Comment: are you sure that's the only code that binds to the done button?

Comment: Yeah, from the storyboard I can verify that there's only one action sent from the Done button. The Done button is also stored as an outlet so that it can be disabled in some other situations, but that shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: How was this view controller shown originally? The existence of the back button with the back arrow suggests that this was pushed, not presented.

Comment: A navigation controller was modally presented; this view controller was pushed on to that nav controller. The done button is meant to dismiss the whole modal flow - and it _did_ do that successfully, until iOS 11.

Comment: I've attached another screenshot to the question showing the storyboard which sets up the modally-presented navigation controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In preparing your [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you noticed that the problem was the presence of the `UISearchController`. I noticed that even after I pushed to the second page view controller (past the view controller with the `UISearchController`), that the search controller was still there:

[image: search controller still in hierarchy]

If you set the `isActive` to `false` when the view disappears, this problem goes away.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false
}
```

And, when this is done, the dismissal works as expected.

---

My original answer, suggesting that you want to dismiss the navigation controller, not the presenting view controller, is below.

---

If you presented the navigation controller modally, and then pushed a few view controllers from there, you don't want to dismiss the `presentingViewController`, but rather the `navigationController`, e.g.:

```
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Or, alternatively, create an unwind action on your view controller to which you want to return:

```
@IBAction func unwindHome(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // this is intentionally blank
}
```

Then you can create an unwind segue right in IB:

[image]

Or if you have to do it programmatically, create an unwind segue between the view controller and the "exit" outlet, and then you can `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However, when I switch to use an unwind action, I still have the exact same problem!

I noticed that I'm only seeing this issue when an ancestor VC in the navigation controller has a `searchController`. I know that sounds mad, but I'm using the exact same VC and dismiss method in another storyboard without issue...

When I perform `navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)`, the disappearance is no longer animated (even though I pass `animated: true`): the view instantaneously disappears.

Comment: Let me amend my previous comment (I missed another piece of code dismissing without animation): 

The first time I call `navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)`, it _does not dismiss the view_!. I have to tap Done twice, and it calls my `doneWasPressed` method twice. Only the second call of `navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)` has effect.

Again, this also is only the case when an ancestor has a searchController in its navigation item. Switching to a search bar positioned in the view instead removes this problem...

Comment: I'd suggest you creating the [smallest possible reproducible example of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because we can't reproduce your problem based upon the information above. Create a blank project and add stuff that you see in your actual app until you have something that reproduces the problem. (Generally, in the process of creating this MCVE, you'll figure out the problem yourself!)

Comment: OK, I created the smallest reproducible example. It's a _very_ minimal project, and the problem is still present. Runs on XCode 9 (GM), issue is present when running on iPhone 8 Plus (and others). Take a look: https://github.com/AndrewBennet/ModalDismissIssueExample

Comment: @AndrewBennet - Good [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It appears that the root of the problem was, as you diagnosed, the search controller. When you start to search, it becomes `isActive`. When you push to the next scene, it's still active. If you set `isActive` to `false` when you push, then the dismiss works like you would have expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've now got everything working as it should be :)

Comment: I've had similar issues and I think it is because when a search begins, a UISearchController will be presented. I.e. my view controller's `presentedViewController` is now non-nil. If I present another view controller I get a log message saying I'm already presenting. I solve that by looping through presentedViewControllers to find the top-most one and present from there. And when dismissing I would usually dismiss from self, but there's the extra search controller in the stack of presented view controllers and that causes the glitch. Calling dismiss on the presented VC (or its parent) works.

Comment: ...continued. On iOS 10 (and earlier), when a search begins there is NO presented `UISearchController` and none of these issues occur.